# Creating multiple UIImageViews in Xcode- One technique builds fast, one is slow. What's the difference?

Tags: swift

I can create image Views through a traditional for loop, and it builds lightning fast:

```
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        let overImage = UIImage(named: "\(i).png")
        var overImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: imageSize))
        overImageView.image = overImage
        gridImageView.addSubview(overImageView)
        overImageView.alpha = 0
    }
```

If I run this code iterating through a Dictionary, it takes forever, and my CPU spikes up to 1,000,000%:

```
    let overImageUrls = [(name: "1.png"), (name: "2.png"), (name: "3.png"), (name: "4.png"), (name: "5.png"), (name: "6.png"), (name: "7.png"), (name: "8.png"), (name: "9.png")]

    for (name) in overImageUrls {
        let image = UIImage(named: name)
        var overImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: imageSize))
        overImageView.image = image
        gridImageView.addSubview(overImageView)
        overImageView.alpha = 0
    }
```

What's the difference? Why would the second example cause such a different build time/CPU load?

Comment: Interesting. In other contexts, if I try to do something similar, the compiler genreates an error message that says "Cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label". Maybe they meant to prohibit this pattern and this one slipped past them, causing some degenerate behavior. But I think you can simplify it to `let overImageUrls = ["1.png", "2.png", ...]` and then `for name in overImageUrls { ... }`, and you don't see this curious behavior.

Comment: Apples and oranges.  These loops are not identical.  Moreover, what *exactly* are you timing?

Comment: I'm only timing them because the Second example was taking around 60 seconds to build and run. The for loop happens nearly instantly. I would have never tried the for loop if the first method (dictionary) didn't take so long. One other detail, Xcode starts showing "indexing" all the time when I use the Dictionary method. If I comment it out and build, it's immediately more responsive.